# "produce best output" versus "produce the best output"

Tags: definite-articles, superlative-degree

I've heard people say both:

> Try and produce **best** output.

or

> Try and produce **the best** output.

Which is the right one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Try and produce the best output.

This is the right one. Before [superlative adjectives](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-superlative_3.htm) you should use "the".

Comment: Does this hold in all cases of "try and"? It often sounds incorrect to me. Is "Try and make it to tonight's concert." correct?

Comment: @cam8001: I believe yes, but this has got nothing with superlative adjectives.

Answer (score 2):

"Try to produce the best output" is more correct.

Answer (score 2):

I do not find "Produce best output" normal in any dialect of English that I recognise.

As Manoochehr says, superlatives usually need "the", but there is an idiom "for best results" (typically on instruction sheets and clothing labels), and I wonder if somebody has tried to generalise that construction.

I can't see that "try and" has any relevance.